# How can I make bruteforce password recovery software using with parallel computing tech

Tags: delphi, cluster-computing, parallel-processing

How can I make bruteforce password recovery software in delphi using with parallel computing technologies for md5 Algorithms!

Can someone tell me some advise?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can with OmniThreadLibrary.

Comment: @JamieHutton - No not like this, I mean is not with multiple threads. I mean is with more than hundred thousands computers

Comment: All my users know it, don't worry about that.

Comment: Do some one have information or some link about distributed grid system ?

Comment: [GPU](http://gpu.sourceforge.net/faq.php) is an experimental computer grid network (P2P) for Monte Carlo simulations and randomized algorithms. It is open source written in Delphi.

Comment: Voted to close for asking an "does anyone have teh codez" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parallel computing makes sense in today's day and age due to most of our CPUs having multiple cores.

However, your performance is not a one to one relationship with the number of threads. You'll most likely want just one or two threads per core.

You can use TThread class to create multiple threads in Delphi.

[Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) has a MD5 hash function in the IdHashMessageDigest unit.

Make sure that you know the exact algorithm, including the use of any [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), before you attempt to reverse an MD5 hash through brute force.

If there was no salt used, I think there are probably [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) available for MD5 on the web already, where you can just do a search.

You'll most likely want to try a [dictionary attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) prior to trying every possibility. There are many dictionaries available for download on the Internet, easily found on Google.

With more specific questions, we can give more specific answers.

**Edit**

To create a grid computing system, whereby you distribute the work to many computers, you'll need a central management server that doles out pieces of the work to the other computers. If the results aren't returned within a certain time threshold, then you put it back in the queue.

You'll need to build a simple framework where you can pass in a few parameters that represent a work load to each client, upon request. Perhaps it's a range of values to try.

The client should contact the server to receive a piece of work, and it always report back when it has finished the work, or perhaps immediately if it makes a hit.

If you have enough computers, consider each client building a local rainbow table for each possible salt, utilizing the storage from each client.

**Example of work queue**

Here's an example of a piece of work that would be sent as a parameter, and most likely stored in a database.

You want to attack the hash SLDFJIJ44adsf.

Here are the tables:

```
Hashes
----------------------------
TargetHash      Answer
----------------------------
SLDFJIJ44adsf   NULL   

Work
----------------------------
TargetHash      Type        RangeBegin      RangeEnd    DateAssigned
----------------------------
SLDFJIJ44adsf   Dictionary  aardvark        beaver      2011-12-16
SLDFJIJ44adsf   Dictionary  beavis          zoology     2011-12-16
SLDFJIJ44adsf   Brute       aaaa            ZZZZ        2011-12-16
SLDFJIJ44adsf   Brute       aaaaa           MZZZZ       2011-12-16
```

Comment: No not like this, I mean is not with multiple threads. I mean is with more than hundred thousands computers

Comment: You can write a distributed grid system, sure. You'll be using Indy and TThread. However, there are cheaper things than computers. Game platforms are often below cost so that you buy the games, but have great computing power. Try a network of Playstation 3s.

Comment: Don't worry about cost of the computers, I already have hundred thousands computers on my hand but have not find a library or some tutorial link about distributed grid system on internet :(

Comment: I updated my answer to give you some more basic instructions for a grid system. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I know, it should be like this but I didn't catch the how can I divide the proccess for share with all of my clients :(

Comment: You'll most likely want to use a database to keep track of the work. You'll need to split it up into logical parts. I recommend keeping the pieces of work small but let computers who are returning often download more pieces at a time.

Comment: I was find this opensource library do someone know like this library in delphi ? http://www.ohloh.net/p/ngrid

Comment: What do you mean "I already have
hundred thousands computers on my hand"?

Comment: I mean, My video and cinema watching software(for free) installed to around 700,000 computers in all around the world. And I am selling seo services(organic hit google vs..) and advertisement or another services using with 700,000 computers. Now I want to open a new website for recover the passwords

Comment: What about the legal implications of running password cracking code on people's machines without their consent? Indeed what about legal implications of running any sort of code on other peoples machines without their consent?

Comment: They agree my agreements before downloading my software. You don't need to think more about that. The legal policy depend on the your country rule! In my country if people agree the my agreements that's enough for it, I don't give bad to they are computers! I am not a hacker. You have to think this like as a business

Comment: And David, if you or some good software developer want to make it for me, I can share the pie with him for recovery website. People will pay money over Paypal and need to write his md5 hash, we will take 10$ or 5$ per password. I think like this business can make alot of money then others! What do you think? And all is legal with the website.

Comment: I doubt the courts would agree with you in a great many countries in the world. Anyway, that's your business not mine so I will say no more.

Comment: Don't scare too much:) life is not like this. Anyway, the bill gates said "don't ask me how I make my first million dollars, but I can tell you one by one another all my billion dollars" this is so clear answer I think:)